# Check if each element of one list is a multiple of all the elements of another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have two lists; S and T.
I want to check if each element of T is a multiple of all the elements of S. Then append that element of T to a new list V if the condition is true for all elements of S.

Input

```
S = [2, 4]
T = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Expected Output

```
V = [4, 8, 12, 16]
```

I tried this code below but got a wrong output;

```
V = [i for i in T for j in S if i % j == 0]
print(V)
```

Current wrong output

```
V = [4, 4, 6, 8, 8, 10, 12, 12, 14, 16, 16]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `all()` to check if all conditions are True:

```
S = [2, 4]
T = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

V = [i for i in T if all(i % j == 0 for j in S)]
print(V)
```

Comment: Beautiful! It works great. Thanks for your help Wasif.